# Get backing file descriptor for Node file stream

Tags: node.js

When I've opened a file as a stream, e.g. with [`fs.createWriteStream`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options), how do I reliably get the backing file descriptor of the stream?

(I need the file descriptor to call functions like [`fs.futimes`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_futimes_fd_atime_mtime_callback) on it.)

There appears to be `stream.fd`, but it's `null` for a fraction of a second before it gets set. So how do I get the file descriptor once it's available?

Comment: It might be easier to pass a file descriptor to the stream instead. I don't know the API off the top of my head.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var stream = fs.createWriteStream('./something.txt');

stream.on('open', function (fd) {
  // here is an fd
})
```

this is actually documented (http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_event_open_1), whereas both `fd` option and property are not

Comment: The stream.fd property is set here: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L1670

    this.fd = fd;
    this.emit('open', fd);

right before the open event is sent.

Comment: @SamMikes What he is saying is that it isn't documented and therefore isn't necessarily a public API, not that it isn't accessible other ways. The `open` event is the documented way to access the file descriptor.